# Is there a way to influence automatic sound settings in Flash / AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, audio, rtmfp

I am creating a voice enabled application in Flash using RTMFP and I noticed that the Flash plugin automatically regulates down the sound volume of other processes/applications (at least on Windows) as soon as a RTMFP stream is opened and starts playing - very similar to the way Skype does this. Furthermore it seems that Flash also regulates itself (!) down in volume as soon as the Microphone is accessed what is quite contraproductive in group conferences. See: http://i50.tinypic.com/2415r4k.jpg

So, what I am trying to do is to get access to the automatic sound settings, either to disable or to set my own rules for them because the defaults don't work out very well in my oppinion. Unfortunately, searching on this topic did not raise any usable results so I hope that maybe someone else has managed to do this already and is able to give me a hint.

If this is not possible in general it would still be sufficient to disable automatic sound settings on every NetStream opened so that at least these are always at 100% volume or more, depending on the case. Does anyone know if manually setting the volume/gain on a NetStream instance overrides the automatic settings made by the plugin? Or is the automatic sound setting always overriding that/adding to that settings and entirely out of a developer's influence?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more of a Windows 7 problem and not directly related to Flash. You can change this behavior if you check your settings in the Control Panel: Sound - Communications - "When Windows detects communications activity".

There is no workaround from the Flash point of view, as the operating system itself controls this volume adjustment. If you use SoundTransform(1) on your NetStream, the Flash Player outputs the full volume, but the Windows sound manager is one level above and turns it down again.